# Provide input to software from separate python standalone executable

Tags: python, input, software-design

I have a python script called RIIC.py, which has a corresponding standalone .exe file called RIIC.exe. The software I want to both launch AND provide input to (via RIIC.exe) is called RES.exe. Note that RES.exe retains GUI capabilities for user I/O and does NOT allow I/O from a command line interface. I know python has the capability to LAUNCH this software but I am unsure if I am able to provide INPUT to RES.exe directly from RIIC.exe. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: So this other program only takes input via a GUI window?  Look into pyautogui...

Comment: From your question, it's not clear how the input to `RES.exe` is achieved and what `RIIC.py` has to do with both of these binaries.